# If / else Statement with Prompt

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am super new like day 3 looking and typing code new and I am trying to run this code but it is not working. I have searched and searched but I don't know what I have messed up. Any help would be appreciated.

*note if I take the else away it will run but it does not follow the rule <500 it just says go away to anything you put in.

```
var budget = prompt('What is your budget?');
if (budget < 500); {
alert('GO AWAY');
}
else  (budget >= 500); {
alert('That will do');
```

Comment: `else  if (budget >= 500) {` - also remove the `;` following the conditions

Comment: In this case you can just use `else`, because the `else if` condition will evaluate `true` if the first condition is false. You don't need to re-evaluate the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple errors here. Change what you have to this:

```
var budget = prompt('What is your budget?');
if (parseInt(budget) < 500) {
alert('GO AWAY');
}
else {
alert('That will do');
}
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ynvkjmdt/)

Basically you had a `;` after your if statement and after the parenthesis. This is not needed. Also, `else` does not accept parameters.

Answer (score 2):

It's a `else if` not else .And remove the `;`  in if and  else statement .

**Note***

For your case you have one condition is enough .less `500` second else always match `500` and above.if you have more number of condition you could use `elseif`

```js
var budget = prompt('What is your budget?');
if (budget < 500) {
  alert('GO AWAY');
} else{
  alert('That will do');
}
```

Comment: Why does this get an upvote? If budget isn't below 500 then the else situation is always above 500 if the budget is defined...

Answer (score 1):

The second check is redundant. And also, you had `;` after `if` and `else`, remove those:

```js
var budget = prompt('What is your budget?');
if (budget < 500) {
  alert('GO AWAY');
} else {
  alert('That will do');
}
```

Comment: Why does this get an upvote? If budget isn't below 500 then the else situation is always above 500 if the budget is defined...

Comment: @KarelG True, thanks for pointing that out. It was still working though, so I don't really see the problem with the upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) statements is more simple to use [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and get a variable `message` out of your logic.

Than call `alert(message)` only once:

```js
var budget = prompt('What is your budget?'),
    message = budget < 500 ? 'GO AWAY' : 'That will do';

alert(message);
```

Note: the previous answers have well pointed all the errors on the OP.

Comment: +1 for ternary, however the OP should probably not do that seeing his/her expertise level. It's best to stay in the if/else realm for now.

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet agree with you.. I have added links in the description in order to show the proper documentation and examples from both `if...else` and Conditional (ternary) Operator

Answer (score -1):

```
var budget = prompt("What's your budget ?");

if(budget < 500) {
    
    alert("GO AWAY");
}

else {
    alert("that will do");
}
```

Comment: Could you include some text explaining what you did to fix the issue? thanks :)

Comment: This adds nothing that isn't in much older existing answers. It's also a code-only dump with no explanation of the problem or the solution.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.